# TypeError: undefined is not a function when unit-testing custom redux hook

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a custom hook, that calls a saga function that in turn calls an axios api, when testing this function im getting

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

I just want to test if this function got called.

**postsHook.test.tsx**

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import usePostsHook from "./postsHook";
import { initCommentUpdates, getPostsInit } from "../actions/postActions";
import { getPosts } from "../selectors/selectors";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

describe("usePostsHook hook", () => {
    const [posts] = renderHook(() => usePostsHook());
    expect(posts).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
});
```

**postsHooks.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { initCommentUpdates, getPostsInit } from "../actions/postActions";
import { getPosts } from "../selectors/selectors";
function usePostsHooks() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const posts = useSelector(getPosts());
    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPostsInit());
        console.log("post hooks got called");
        dispatch(initCommentUpdates());
    }, []);
    return [posts];
}

export default usePostsHooks;
```

Comment: You need to wrap your render with a redux store & mock the selector and the dispatch function

Comment: Can you demonstrate how i would be able to do this ?

Comment: Of course, posted a partial answer, tell me whenever I need to add or explain something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`posts` is not a function in your hook, but something selected from store and I presume is the return from your API. so `expect(posts).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);` is natural since it is not a function.

To test whether your dispatch occurred or not, you need to mock it. Here is an example I use in my tests:

```
import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';

// this mock will be the dispatch function that redux returns on useDispatch()
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

beforeAll(() => {
  // tells useDispatch to return the mocked dispatch
  ReactRedux.useDispatch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockDispatch);
  // tells useSelector to return an empty array
  ReactRedux.useSelector = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => []);
});


beforeEach(() => {
  // clear the mocks to refresh their calls info
  ReactRedux.useDispatch.mockClear();
  mockDispatch.mockClear();
});
```

Later, in your test

```
expect(posts).toEqual([])
expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(getPostsInit())
```

The thing here is that you are just unit testing your hook, ie: It returns what `useSelector` returns, it fires some dispatches, without knowing what is the actual real implementation of `useSelector` or `useDispatch`

Comment: about to try this out, not sure why this got downvoted.

Comment: Let's wait for the person that downvoted both the question and the answer to show up :) I will edit to add the mock for the selector as well, because firing the actual useSelector will result in an error: cannot find redux store. But the technique is the same when mocking the dispatch

Comment: Im using typescript(tsx) and im getting `Property 'mockClear' does not exist on type `

Comment: please print ReactRedux in the console and tell me what it contains ?.also make sure you import it like this `import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux'`.

Comment: it prints out a list of properties, like connect, useDispatch, etc. However mockClear doesn't seem to be a method on the list of properties which is why i got the error.

Comment: I think you were writing that the missing property is useDispatch in your comment.
the `mockClear` is executed on mocked properties.

Comment: yeah i checked its not a property within useDispatch.

Comment: So, we mock our function using `jest`, and then we can manipulate it.

Comment: @Inceptor I think i need to read more information on this, and figure this out, i appreciate the support.

Comment: `ReactRedux.useDispatch.mockClear()` was the issue, `mockDispatch.mockClear` worked.

Comment: So from what i understand,  `expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(getPostsInit());` tests to see if this function got fired in postsHooks.tsx

Comment: This expect will assert that your dispatch was called with a `getPostsInit()` action

Comment: yeah this is working now, how would you test the selector method, do i have to pass in mockData or something. To see if expects the same api data ?

Comment: Actually, in my answer we mocked useSelector to return whatever we want, then we assert it. The idea is to assert that you get what results from the useSelector (data is whatever comes from the store). Testing the selector itself should be a part in another file . The idea is that you test each portion of code separately and independently

Comment: Ok i understand, thanks again for the help, would you know where i can find more documentation on redux hook testing etc ?, im using `testing-library/react-hooks`